# About parsing JSON with Python

Tags: python, json

So I find myself parsing elements in JSON teidously. Im probably just not "doing it right."

```
Import json

E1= jsondata['someElement'][0]['theElementIWant][1]
E2= jsondata['someElement'][1]['theElementIWant][3]
```

Now, If I iterate through `someElement` I know that "The Element I want" will be after that. In cruel fasion though, there are 20 elements in that list. I have no clue where its at.

I could at a nested loop in there, but my execution time would be 2n. :( 
Not ideal. How would you do this differently?

Comment: Can you post an example of your data?

Comment: Sounds like you need a loop and you need to leverage the functions inside your imported json module.